# Three badges for reaching a particular number of upvotes in one day

Tags: feature-request, badge-request

**I now realize that this is not a good idea.**

I'd like to have three one-time badges for obtaining a particular number of upvotes in one day.

- Bronze: Get 20 upvotes
- Silver: Get 40 upvotes on at least 8 different answers
- Gold: Get 100 upvotes on at least 15 different answers

The bronze is to reduce confusion about the rep cap. Currently, this is used for Mortarboard, but that also counts the accepted answers and the bounties. I think this pair would reduce confusion further.

The silver and the gold are to compensate once for the extra upvotes. I have put a lower bound on the number of different answers to make sure that one doesn't get it from one answer on an extremely popular question, since that would already yield a good answer or great answer badge.

Just to be clear, I do not mean this to be an alternative to mortarboard, epic, legendary.

Comment: (Disclaimer: Not the downvoter): Would this be merely upvotes, or net votes (i.e. needing 100 net upvotes for gold)?

Comment: @HDE226868 I don't really care.

Comment: And what is the positive behavior that we want to stimulate by having this badges?

Comment: @rene It encourages to post more answers even after reaching the cap.

Comment: And you expect the quality to remain high on those even more answers?

Comment: How many users did stop posting answers right after they hit the rep-cap?

Comment: @rene If the quality doesn't remain high they won't get the badge. There won't be so much upvotes on old posts. Note that with 40 upvotes on 8 different posts I mean that the upvotes have to come from 8 different posts, not that 8 posts have to be posted on the day to get the badge.

Comment: I think badges should be used as a stimulus  for positive behavior. I don't think users that hit the rep-cap will stop answering so I don't see a need for those badges. Unless you provide evidence that proves me wrong...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Badges are there to encourage good behavior. There isn't one point in your proposal that indicates this encourages anything good. It seems to me this encourages bad behavior and the *Fastest Gun* kind of problems since you encourage people to answer a lot of questions with a ton of up-votes.

Besides that, I see no use in another set of badges having almost the same requirements as some existing badges. I think this set of badges doesn't bring any value, it only increase confusion, instead of taking any away (is there then?).

Comment: [this seems to be behavior](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251755/839601) such a badge would encourage

Answer (score 10):

I can't see any value in this.

If you're hitting the rep cap - which you will be with these numbers of votes - you'll have got the [Mortarboard](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/50/mortarboard) badge (which is equivalent to your bronze badge suggestion anyway) and you'll be one step closer to [Epic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/51/epic) and [Legendary](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/52/legendary).

Comment: You haven't read the question. Mortarboard is not equivalent to my bronze badge. In fact, I explain why it is useful to have both badges.

Comment: @wythagoras - Mortarboard *is* equivalent to your bronze badge. If you get 20 upvotes on answers you'll have hit the rep cap. Mortarboard used to only count votes but that confused people no end so it was modified to what it is now.

Comment: Maybe it was equivalent. But it is not equivalent. You can earn Mortarboard from 17 upvotes and 2 accepts. You don't earn my bronze badge using the proposal. As I said, this should reduce confusion.

Comment: @wythagoras - nope. It'll increase confusion. "I earned Mortarboard but I didn't get wythagoras's bronze badge - what gives?"

Comment: @wythagoras accepts don't count towards Motarboard with accepts as its in the same class as a bounty. Its extra rep not counted towards the cap.

Comment: Not to the cap, but it does count to Mortarboard. @Dom